# How to use a class's return in other class?

Tags: python

Here is what I wrote. A program about Geometric Object and I'm trying to use the GeometricObject.**str**(self) in the class Circle's str function, but it doesn't work. I tried many ways and it still has some error.

```
import math

class GeometricObject(object):
     def __init__(self, color = "white", filled = True):
        self.color = color
        self.filled = filled

     def getColor(self):
        return self.color

     def setColor(self, color):
        self.color = color

     def isFilled(self):
        return self.filled

     def setFilled(self, filled):
        self.filled = filled

     def __str__(self):
       return "color: " + self.color + \
             " and filled: " + str(self.filled)

class Circle(object):
     def __init__(self, radius = 1, color = "white", filled = True):
         self.radius = radius
         self.color = color
         self.filled = filled

     def __str__(self):
         return "Circle: radius = " + str(self.radius) + \
               GeometricObject.__str__(self)

     def getArea(self):
         return (math.pi * self.radius**2)

     def getPerimeter(self):
         return (math.pi * 2 * self.radius)

class Triangle(object):

   def __init__(self, side1 = 1, side2 = 1, side3 = 1, color = "white", filled = True):
    self.side1 = side1
    self.side2 = side2
    self.side3 = side3
    self.color = color
    self,filled = filled

   def __str__(self):
    return "Triangle: side1 = " + str(self.side1) + \
           " side2 = " + str(self.side2) + \
           " side3 = " + str(self.side3) + \
           " color: " + str(self.color) +\
           " filled: " + str(self.filled)

   def getArea(self):
    s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
    area = sqrt(s(s - side1)(s - side2)(s - side3))
    return area

def getPerimter(self):
    return (side1 + side2 + side3)

def main():
#Testing Circle class
print "Entering input values for a circle"
r = input('Enter value for radius: ')

c1 = Circle(r)

print c1
print "%.2f" % c1.getArea()
print "%.2f" % c1.getPerimeter()
print c1.getColor()
print c1.isFilled()

#Testing Triangle class
print "\nEntering input values for a traingle"
s1 = input('Enter value for side1: ')
s2 = input('Enter value for side2: ')
s3 = input('Enter value for side3: ')
color = raw_input('Enter color of the triangle: ')
filled = input('Is the triangle filled (1/0)? ')
filled = (filled == 1)

t1 = Triangle(s1, s2, s3, color, filled)

print t1
print "%.2f" % t1.getArea()
print "%.2f" % t1.getPerimeter()
print t1.getColor()
print t1.isFilled()

main()
```

But it keeps telling me that,

```
Entering input values for a circle
Enter value for radius: 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\wxwdd_000\Desktop\CSC131\Lab_5.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\wxwdd_000\Desktop\CSC131\Lab_5.py", line 71, in main
    print c1
  File "C:\Users\wxwdd_000\Desktop\CSC131\Lab_5.py", line 32, in __str__
    GeometricObject.__str__(self)
TypeError: unbound method __str__() must be called with GeometricObject instance as first argument (got Circle instance instead)
>>>
```

How can i fix the **str** function?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean for Circle and Triangle to inherit from GeometricObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to have your subclasses inherit from `GeometricObject`.

Change these:

```
class Circle(object):
class Triangle(object):
```

to these:

```
class Circle(GeometricObject):
class Triangle(GeometricObject):
```

Additional note: You should probably call `GeometricObject.__init__` to set the properties `Triangle` and `Circle` inherit from `GeometricObject` instead of assigning them directly. If `GeometricObject.__init__` did something more complex with its arguments, the subclass constructors would either not handle it properly or become too tied to the superclass's implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

I f you want to inherit it should be like this
`class circle(GeometricObject):` and also you can call GeometricObjects str method using [super()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) inbuilt function call like `super(circle,self).str(arg)`

Hope this helps